# Synchronize profiles across servers (.vimrc and .bashrc)

Tags: bash, sync, bashrc

I'm on a few different servers on any given day. I'm starting to really tweak two files in my bash profile: .vimrc and alias.sh. Would anyone have a recommended way to save and sync these two files. Perhaps using rsync or unison (over ssh using a predefined shared key)? Has anyone set this up before?

Comment: Did you try Dropbox?

Comment: That's not a bad option but I have my own server. I'd like to use rsync or unison. I'm just curious what other folks are doing. I'm hesitant towards dropbox because these are development and production servers. I'd like to not run more processes on these servers. A manual rsync may be all I need.

Comment: A version control system like subversion or git.

Comment: @geirha - That comment should really be down in the answers section below as it is a *great* idea. Thanks!!

Comment: See also [Tips for putting ~ under source control](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1875)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a version control system like subversion or git. As a bonus, if used correctly, you get the answer to the inevitable question; *Why on earth did I put that in there?*

Comment: can you elaborate on that second sentence of yours?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I'm assuming he's talking about the log messages for the commits providing documentation for your changes.

Comment: To update everyone, I've started this today using bitbucket. So far in the repo, I have the .bashrc, .vimrc, alias.sh (a custom alias file), and .vim/ (folder).